# How to avoid "select n+1" pattern in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5, linqkit

I have a query (including LinqKit) of the form:

```
Expression<Func<Country, DateTime, bool>> countryIndepBeforeExpr = 
  (ct, dt) => ct.IndependenceDate <= dt;
DateTime someDate = GetSomeDate();
var q = db.Continent.AsExpandable().Select(c =>
  new 
  {
    c.ID,
    c.Name,
    c.Area,
    Countries = c.Countries.AsQueryable()
                 .Where(ct => countryIndepBeforeExpr.Invoke(ct, someDate))
                 .Select(ct => new {ct.ID, ct.Name, ct.IndependenceDate})
  });
```

Now I want to iterate through `q`... but since the `Countries` property of each element is of type `IQueryable`, it will be lazy loaded, causing n+1 queries to be executed, which isn't very nice.

What is the correct way to write this query so that all necessary data will be fetched in a single query to the db?

**EDIT**

Hm, well it might have helped if I had actually run a Sql trace before asking this question.  I *assumed* that because the inner property was of type `IQueryable` that it would be lazy-loaded... but after doing some actual testing, it turns out that Linq to Entities is smart enough to run the whole query at once.

Sorry to waste all your time.  I would delete the question, but since it already has answers, I can't.  Maybe it can serve as some kind of warning to others to *test* your hypothesis before assuming it to be true!

Comment: This really has more to do with the Linq provider than Linq itself. You should probably tag this question with the appropriate provider (EF, Linq-to-SQL, etc.).

Comment: Why do you reference countries in a continent object? Shouldn't it be the other way around? It would be much simpler for the request. You gather all the countries from `countryIndepBeforeExpr` then select the continents and do whatever you want to do.

Comment: @Ocelot20 - added tags

Comment: @keysharpener - don't be distracted by the particular implementation.  My project has nothing to do with geography; I'm just using the continent/country relationship to make it intuitively obvious to you what I'm trying to do without having to explain the business rules of my project domain.

Comment: You can make this much simpler by capturing the `someDate` variable in the expression, which will then become a `Expression<Func<Country,bool>>` that you can use as `Where(countryIndepBeforeExpr )`, without LinqKit. It will probably also get the countries in one query. I also think you left out too much, because the expression has apparently been compiled, and when I use `AsExpandable()` this way I get the infamous "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method".

Comment: Sorry @GertArnold, you're right, I was writing the code from memory.  AsExpandable belongs outside.  Will edit.

Answer (score 1):

Include countries to your model when you call for continents. With something like this:

```
var continents = db.Continent.Include(c => c.Countries).ToArray();
```

Then you can make your linq operations without iQueryable object.

Comment: +1 fair suggestion, but it has the unwanted side effect of dragging along *all* data from the Country records.  I only want a small number of fields.  And perhaps I'll also want to take some data from tables to which Country has a FK... if I start including all related tables, it's going to get ugly.

Comment: @Shaul If you wanna avoid both problems (retrieve all which is needed => no n+1, but not more that what's is needed => no Include), I don't see any other solution than using anonymous types or probably rather "ViewModel" classes (well custom "non-entity" classes), and select only what you need...

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this should work (moving `AsExpandable()` to root of `IQueryable`):

```
var q = db.Continent
          .AsExpandable()
          .Select(c => new 
          {
              c.ID,
              c.Name,
              c.Area,
              Countries = c.Countries
                  .Where(ct => countryIndepBeforeExpr.Invoke(ct, someDate))
                  .Select(ct => new {ct.ID, ct.Name, ct.IndependenceDate})
});
```

If not, create two `IQueryable` and join them together:

```
var continents = db.Continents;
var countries = db.Countries
                  .AsExpandable()
                  .Where(c => countryIndepBeforeExpr.Invoke(c, someDate))
                  .Select(c => new { c.ID, c.Name, c.IndependenceDate });

var q = continents.GroupJoin(countries,
    continent => continent.ID,
    country => country.ContinentId,
    (continent, countries) => new
    {
        continent.ID,
        continent.Name,
        continent.Area,
        Countries = countries.Select(c => new
        {
            c.ID,
            c.Name,
            c.IndependenceDate
        })
    });
```